# Geoserver REST api and Cyrillic

Tags: geoserver

I try to create a style using Geoserver REST api. Its works fine but cyrillic symbols not work. I send sld with this header:

```
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""ISO-8859-1""?>
```

Befor make request i encoding sld:

```
wRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
wRequest.ContentType = @"text/xml;charset=""ISO-8859-1""";

var iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] data = utf8.GetBytes(body);
byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, data);
```

But when i open style i see that here is another header:

```
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

And cyrrilic converts into `?` symbols.
Whats can be wrong here?

My URL `"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/styles&name=style_001A000D9338"`

ANd simple sld what i post:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version=\ "1.0.0\" xsi:schemaLocation=\ "http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd\" xmlns=\ "http://www.opengis.net/sld\" xmlns:ogc=\ "http://www.opengis.net/ogc\" xmlns:xlink=\ "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" xmlns:xsi=\ "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">
<UserLayer>
    <LayerFeatureConstraints>
        <FeatureTypeConstraint/> </LayerFeatureConstraints>
    <UserStyle>
        <Name>style_001A000D9338</Name>
        <Title>Грунты</Title>
        <Abstract></Abstract>
        <FeatureTypeStyle>
            <Name>001900003A79</Name>
            <Title>Галечниковые и гравийные поверхности\\площадь</Title>
            <Abstract>abstract</Abstract>
            <Rule>
                <Name>0</Name>
                <Title>Галечниковые и гравийные поверхности\\площадь [*-*]</Title>
                <Abstract></Abstract>
                <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>Style</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal>001900003A79</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </ogc:Filter>
                <PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <Fill>
                        <CssParameter name=\ "fill-opacity\">
                            <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                        </CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name=\ "fill\">
                            <ogc:Literal>#FFFFFF</ogc:Literal>
                        </CssParameter>
                    </Fill>
                </PolygonSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
        </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </UserLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Here what i finnaly got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.0.0">
<sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>style_001A000D9338</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
        <sld:Name>style_001A000D9338</sld:Name>
        <sld:Title>??????</sld:Title>
        <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
            <sld:Name>001900003A79</sld:Name>
            <sld:Title>???????????? ? ????????? ???????????\???????</sld:Title>
            <sld:Abstract>abstract</sld:Abstract>
            <sld:Rule>
                <sld:Name>0</sld:Name>
                <sld:Title>???????????? ? ????????? ???????????\??????? [*-*]</sld:Title>
                <sld:Abstract/>
                <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>Style</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal>001900003A79</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </ogc:Filter>
                <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <sld:Fill>
                        <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</sld:CssParameter>
                        <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0</sld:CssParameter>
                    </sld:Fill>
                </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            </sld:Rule>
        </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: please show us a short SLD file and the exact URL you use to post it

Comment: @iant raw parameter partically helps. When i open sld file with notepad its looks prety, but in geoserver sld editor cirillic symbols still unreadable.I think its not a critical becouse in legend cirillic looks normal.